# Display LiDAR data in E00 (interchange file) on maps

Tags: cartography, lidar, overlay, bing-maps, e00

I have Lidar data in E00 files (interchange files). Can I overlay them on some maps like say Bing maps or Geoserver with OpenLayers?

If yes, what is the right way of doing it?

Comment: Shapefile or even better a database (like postgres)

Comment: Yes eventually that will be the way. And i know how to render shapefiles. Problem is i am new to lidar data. So I need some solutions to work with Lidar. To get it into database or shapefiles.  Is the GeoTIFF an option too??  Also when you say a shapefile/db, will it be a points shapefile/db? wont it be too intensive if i try to render high resolution lidar data of say entire texas?

Comment: The Database can be a big as you like - it's the end application that will choke - Bing or Google Maps are limited on the number of features (without clustering). Lidar data will be too intensive for large area for web mapping

Comment: so what are my options to show some elevation overlays on my maps?

Comment: You will need to do some select (maybe random) filtering to limit the amount of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first step is to convert the e00 file to something useful. See:

[Converting E00 vector data to shapefiles: a free and fairly painless approach](http://freegeographytools.com/2007/converting-e00-vector-data-to-shapefiles-a-free-and-fairly-painless-approach), for details if you don't have access to ArcToolBox.

Comment: that sounds like a good start. Say i get the ee0 files in a shapefiles or even a database. Even then, the data i have is of very high resolution and a very large area. If i try to render the points from shapefiles on the map it will be too slow. How do people usually show elevation models on maps?

Comment: Usually as a GeoTiff through GeoServer (but try the shapefile anyway see http://jgrasstechtips.blogspot.com/2011/06/lidar-data-jgrasstools-and-udig.html)

Comment: You can restricting your elevation data to a single return, instead of taking all return values into consideration. Even better if you can take, say, 20% of the sample value, which will reduce amount of data and maintain a "general" elevation picture. There are tools available to extract n% data out of a LIDAR sample (see [this tool](http://www.perrygeo.net/wordpress/?p=38), and [this too](http://www.csc.noaa.gov/digitalcoast/tools/lidarhandler/index.html)).